# sed regex to match ['', 'WR' or 'RN'] + 2-4 digits

Tags: regex, unix, text

I'm trying to do some conditional text processing on Unix and struggling with the syntax.  I want to acheive

```
Find the first 2, 3 or 4 digits in the string
if 2 characters before the found digits are 'WR' (could also be lower case)
    Variable = the string we've found (e.g. WR1234)
    Type = "work request"
else
    if 2 characters before the found digits are 'RN' (could also be lower case)
      Variable = the string we've found (e.g. RN1234)
      Type = "release note"
    else
      Variable = "WR" + the string we've found (Prepend 'WR' to the digits)
      Type = "Work request"
    fi
fi
```

I'm doing this in a Bash shell on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

Thanks in advance,
Karl

Comment: Three example strings, the first and last are work requests, the middle a release note.
WR1234
RN1234
1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you read in your strings but this example should help you get there.  I loop over 4 example strings, `WR1234 RN456 7890 PQ2342`.  You didn't say what to do if the string doesn't match your expected format (`PQ2342` in my example), so my code just ignores it.

```
#!/bin/bash

for string in "WR1234 - Work Request Name.doc" "RN5678 - Release Note.doc"; do
  [[ $string =~ ^([^0-9]*)([0-9]*).*$ ]]
  case ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} in
    "WR")
          var="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
          type="work request"
          echo -e "$var\t-- $type"
          ;;
    "RN")
          var="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
          type="release note"
          echo -e "$var\t-- $type"
          ;;
    "")
          var="WR${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
          type="work request"
          echo -e "$var\t-- $type"
          ;;
  esac
done
```

#### Output

```
$ ./rematch.sh
WR1234  -- work request
RN5678  -- release note
```

Comment: This is great except that I obviously simplified my example too much.  The strings have trailing text e.g. 'WR1234 - Work Request Name.doc'.  How do I cut off the tailing text?  In this example I would like to end up with 'WR1234'

Comment: Thanks.  This is great.  And the '=~' and BASH_REMATCH[i] combination is well worth knowing about.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `perl -pe` instead of `sed` because PERL has such expressive regular expressions.  The following is a bit verbose for the sake of instruction.

**example.txt**:

```
WR1234 - Work Request name.doc
RN456
rn456
WR7890 - Something else.doc
wr789
2456
```

**script.sh**:

```
#! /bin/bash

# search for 'WR' or 'RN' followed by 2-4 digits and anything else, but capture 
# just the part we care about
records="`perl -pe 's/^((WR|RN)([\d]{2,4})).*/\1/i' example.txt`"

# now that you've filtered out the records, you can do something like replace 
# WR's with 'work request'
work_requests="`echo \"$records\" | perl -pe 's/wr/work request /ig' | perl -pe 's/rn/release note /ig'`"

# or add 'WR' to lines w/o a listing
work_requests="`echo \"$work_requests\" | perl -pe 's/^(\d)/work request \1/'`"

# or make all of them uppercase
records_upper=`echo $records | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`

# or count WR's
wr_count=`echo "$records" | grep -i wr | wc -l`
echo count $wr_count

echo "$work_requests"
```

Comment: Yeap, I think I'll take the hint ans learn Perl.  Cause yeah, sed is just to arcane for words.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
string="RN12344 - Work Request Name.doc"
echo "$string" | gawk --re-interval '
{
    if(match ($0,/(..)[0-9]{4}\>/,a ) ){
        if (a[1]=="WR"){
            type="Work release"
        }else if  ( a[1] == "RN" ){
            type = "Release Notes"
        }
        print type
    }
}'
```